# SIGSEGV in php-fpm

Tags: php, strace, shopware

I found several questions that mention problems with php 5.5.x and higher and php-fpm where php crashes with:

```
WARNING: [pool pool_name] child 9757 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 24.790363 seconds from start
```

In the apache error log you can see this message

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/path/to/pool/php56-fcgi-pool_name" aborted: read failed
```

In my setup I run php 5.6.21 and I get this error on a Shopware instance and I can reproduce it. I tried to enable debugging for php, but since Shopware needs the ioncube loader it's not possible to run php with debugging symbols and the ioncube loader.

As a second try I used this script to create traces for every php-fpm instance: https://gist.github.com/hydra35/1893093. For my error this trace looks like this:

```
     0.000036 access("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce/Bootstrap.php", R_OK) = 0
 0.000415 gettimeofday({1462828780, 911678}, NULL) = 0
 0.000042 gettimeofday({1462828780, 911719}, NULL) = 0
 0.000057 gettimeofday({1462828780, 911780}, NULL) = 0
 0.000036 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce/Bootstrap.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17113, ...}) = 0
 0.000057 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000044 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000048 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000045 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000073 gettimeofday({1462828780, 912082}, NULL) = 0
 0.000035 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce/Bootstrap.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17113, ...}) = 0
 0.000051 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000046 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000059 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000042 lstat("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000048 open("/home/user/www/www.example.org/htdocs/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Core/CouchCommerce/Bootstrap.php", O_RDONLY) = 5
 0.000479 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17113, ...}) = 0
 0.000049 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17113, ...}) = 0
 0.000038 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17113, ...}) = 0
 0.000035 mmap(NULL, 17113, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 5, 0) = 0x7fc756a10000
 0.000844 brk(0x2ea5000)            = 0x2ea5000
 0.000359 munmap(0x7fc756a10000, 17113) = 0
 0.000075 close(5)                  = 0
 0.000051 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x3d} ---
 0.051948 +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

How much of the strace is needed to really make a statement? How else is it possible to debug php for this application to solve the error that leads to this crash?

Thanks for your help
Andi

Comment: are you using the right version of ioncube and opcache? i had a same problem because the versions of ioncube and opcache didnt match. i downloaded the newest version and now it works.

Comment: So the opcache comes with the php tar.bz2 package. Therefore I think this should be the right version to fit with this php 5.6.21 the ioncube loader is the one from here for linux 64 bit: https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php. Should be the right one, or not?

Comment: ah i am sorry. i mixed it with zend guard loader :/
I had this issue with zend guard loader not with ioncube. Zend Guard Loader ships its own opcache.so